# traversing through a linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing an insert method for a linked list, and found one thing hard to understand. It works when traversing using this code:

```
class Node {
int data;
Node next;
Node(int d) {
       data = d;
       next = null;
    }
}

public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
    Node conductor = head;
    if(conductor == null){
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
       while(conductor.next != null){
           conductor = conductor.next;
       }
       conductor.next = new Node(data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

but if I change the while loop to :

```
       while(conductor != null){
           conductor = conductor.next;
       }
       conductor = new Node(data);
```

It doesn't work. And I don't understand what the difference is.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: In the first one, after the `while`, `conductor` is the last element in the list. In the second, `conductor` is `null` and not part of the list.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you changed the code to something different, and then you wonder why it’s different? Why don’t you take an example of a short list and work through on loser what it’s doing?

Comment: I see! I misunderstood null. I thought the null pointed by the last node has a reference so that as long as conductor points to that null then it will be part of the list. Now I know null is null, it doesn't hold any reference. Thank you!

Comment: `while(conductor != null){
           conductor = conductor.next;` This will definitely give NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

When **first** loop stops the `conductor` holds a reference to the last node in the list, i.e. it is the one whose `next` is null. It is that node you want to modify, which you can do with your `conductor.next = new Node(data)`.

With the **second** loop it stops when `conductor` is `null` which is completely useless and almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you iterate over the elements until you hit a `null` you will set `conductor` to be a new `Node` which will have no connnection to the rest of the list:

```
[node0] -> [node1] -> `null`   ... [node2] -> null
                                    ^^^-- your inserted element
```

What you want instead is to find the **last** element and attach your new `Node` as the `next` of your last element. This is why it is called a **linked list**. When you `insert` you create a *link* from the last element to the next:

```
[node0] -> [node1] -> [node2] -> null
                       ^^^-- your inserted element
```

Answer (score 0):

let say the linked list

1->2->3->5->null

the loop you have written stops when it reaches the null pointer and creates a new node but not at current next's which breaks the link between "5" and new node you are creating so there will be no new node attached to the linked list.

so we have to stop the loop when we found current next is null and we have to add the new node in current next position

Answer (score -1):

You must understand that your local variable `Node conductor`, is a **reference** to an object, not the object itself, neither a copy of it.

So at the end of the loop `conductor = new Node(data);` just makes this reference **points** to a brand new object. It does not change the list itself.

Comment: Yeah I get it. Thank you very much.